# How to use useContext() within a Compound Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I have a `HeaderAvatarMenu` component which is a dropdown menu, and it has a state of toggle.

```
const ToggleContext = createContext();

const HeaderAvatarMenu = ({ children, ...restProps }) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ToggleContext.Provider value={{ toggle, setToggle }}>
      <Container {...restProps}>{children}</Container>
    </ToggleContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

For this component I have created a compound component `Link` which consumes the context values

```
HeaderAvatarMenu.Link = function ({ children, ...restProps }) {
  const { toggle, setToggle } = useContext(ToggleContext);
  return (
    <ReactLink onClick={() => setToggle((toggle) => !toggle)} {...restProps}>
      {children}
    </ReactLink>
  );
};
```

**Error :**

```
React Hook "useContext" is called in function "HeaderAvatarMenu.Link" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter
```

**package.json**

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-icons": "^3.11.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

What could be the possible solution to use context within compound component?

Comment: `HeaderAvatarMenu.Link = function Link({ children, ...restProps })`   Give your  function a name or `React component names must start with an uppercase letter` it's not got an uppercase.. :)  Saying that, modern JS engines will imply the name, so I'm assuming your getting this error on older browsers.

Comment: I have Chrome Version 87.0.4280.66 (Official Build) (64-bit) latest, i tried naming the function but still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to create Link as an attribute inside HeaderAvatarMenu? That's truly the only unusual part I see in your code

Comment: That's what actually is the requirement, and the code standard am using, so i just need to know how can I useContext within "that" Link component